# where to import modules in flask project

Tags: python, flask

I have been following the flask mega tutorial form Miguel grinberg and the very first "Hello World!" program is confusing me.

More specifically it is the import of the routes module from the **init**.py module that is confusing me.

Below is the **init**.py file:

```
#__init__.py file:

from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

from app import routes
# above line is the source of confusion.
```

Below is the routes.py file

```
from app import app

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return "Hello, world!"
```

Now if I understand correctly, app is an object of class Flask. when we do "from app import app" in routes.py, I understand that we are importing the app object created in **init**.py file.

The code then follows is registering a route for this object.

So my question is why do we need to import this **routes** module in **init**.py?

I mean in routes module, the app object has been imported and a route has been registered on it. So this should reflect on the app object created in **init**.py. So why do we need to import it?

I know that it does not work if we remove the import routes statement. But want to know why.

Edit: Though I have a programming background, I am new to python. So it might be misunderstanding on how python files are executed when projects are executed. Also I think this has to do something with python being an interpreted language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you import anything in python, it actually runs the entire file that you are importing. The `__init__.py` file does not have any information about the routes so by importing it you are essentially providing that information to the app object. In addition, this routes file is never directly ran so that is the only way the views are actually created.

Hope this helps!